# My domain on AWS Route 53 wont propagate

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, nslookup, ns-record

Hi have created a record set for the domain:

**lazycatthemes.com**

on Route 53 (domain was purchased through route 53) and gave it the 4 NS settings that Route 53 told me to configure:

```
ns-368.awsdns-46.com 
ns-1963.awsdns-53.co.uk 
ns-848.awsdns-42.net 
ns-1332.awsdns-38.org
```

When I check it on any one of those DNS servers using the nslookup tool it works:

```
nslookup lazycatthemes.com ns-1963.awsdns-53.co.uk
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  205.251.199.171

Name:    lazycatthemes.com
Address:  54.154.51.71
```

but this doesn't propagate. I've waited 36 hours and I still get this:

```
nslookup lazycatthemes.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find lazycatthemes.com: Server failed
```

I'm not sure what to do next?

Comment: If you check http://whois.domaintools.com/lazycatthemes.com you can see that the DNS servers are not the same as you have listed above. It also says the domain was purchased through GANDI SAS not AWS

Comment: Ha! OK, it turns out that Gandi provisions some of the domains for AWS. So should I change the settings to the WHOIS settings?

Comment: Hmmm, if thats the case I'm guessing you don't have access to anything in Gandi direct. It sounds like something has gone wrong in the provisioning process. As it isn't working it isn't going to harm things to try, but it might be worthwhile creating a support ticket with AWS just to make sure there are no problems going forward

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was the answer:
The name servers displayed on/in the hosted zone are the ones you will want to use. When you have a domain registered with / transferred to AWS, you configure which name servers to use under "Registered domains" in the Route 53 Management Console. Select your domain there and you'll see the current name servers on the details page that appears. If they don't match what you saw on the hosted zone, grab the name servers from the hosted zone and replace the incorrect name servers on the domain.

Comment: I applied this fix, but it takes time until the name servers for the domain are updated. When I had already submitted the request, I check if I couldn't change the NS entry of the hosted zone for the domain instead. It is possible. Now I am think it would have been better to update the hosted zone with the name servers of the domain instead. This change would like be effective much faster.

Comment: I can confirm that copying the values from the hosted zone to the domain worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just transferred from 1and1 or some other registrar, your DNS records are not going to be correct.

**Step 1:**
"Create Hosted Zone", under "Hosted zones" on the left-hand navigation.
This will give you a list of Route53 DNS servers, specifically for your domain.  Don't copy these from a different domain you own, they will likely be different.

Example:

```
ns-XX.awsdns-XX.com
ns-XXXX.awsdns-XX.co.uk
ns-XXX.awsdns-XX.net
ns-XXXX.awsdns-XX.org
```

**Step 2:**
Click on the "Registered domains" link on left-hand navigation.
Select your domain.
Check that "Name servers" is equal to the list of DNS address above.
Otherwise click "Add or edit name servers", and make the list:

Example:

```
ns-XX.awsdns-XX.com
ns-XXXX.awsdns-XX.co.uk
ns-XXX.awsdns-XX.net
ns-XXXX.awsdns-XX.org
```

Replace X with the numbers of your specific DNS.